# Bash : Remove everthing before special caracter

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I got a big json file with text to be modify in each value. If we look a the first entry, it looks like :

```
$ cat description6fr.json | jq '.[0].fr'
Something\nSomethings\n\nSomething\n\nSomething
```

How to cut everything before the first **\n\n** ? I did try many things with sed and awk, but help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Does `\n` here denote single character named newline xor `\n` should be understood as two characters: backslash and lowercase n letter?

Comment: FYI `\n\n` is a string, not a character. `\n` would be a character.

Comment: ^ assuming by `\n` you meant a literal newline of course, but if it's a literal ```\``` followed by a literal `n` then that is also a 2-character string.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `index` to find the match and then slice it:

```
jq '.[0].fr | .[index("\n\n") + 2:]' description6fr.json
```

If the string does not match `\n\n`, this will truncate the first two characters, so you might prefer something like:

```
jq '.[0].fr| if index("\n\n") then .[index("\n\n") + 2:] else . end' description6fr.json
```

you can parameterize that with:

```
jq --argjson s '"\n\n"' 'if index($s) then .[index($s) + 2:] else . end'
```

Comment: Be careful, though.  If you have a string that does not contain. `\n\n`, this will just truncate the first 2 characters, which is probably not what you want.